# How to create a RGB image using PIL from values in a list?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a list of RGB values that I want to create into a 32 x 32 image.
I have tried: 
[Code1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxAan.png)

From the list: 
[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuUtu.png)
Etc. for 1024 RGB values

I have no experience with this library so sorry for misunderstanding something.

Comment: Please include all the code related to the question as text and not in an image.

Comment: Is using PIL a strict requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we can create a 32x32 RGB image with a list of tuples.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = []

for i in range(1024):
    tup = (np.random.randint(0,255),np.random.randint(0,255),np.random.randint(0,255))
    img.append(tup)

im2 = Image.new(mode = 'RGB', size = (32,32))
im2.putdata(img)
im2.save('myimg.png')
```

We can also make it a little more compact, like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = [(np.random.randint(0,255),np.random.randint(0,255),np.random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(1024)]

im2 = Image.new(mode = 'RGB', size = (32,32))
im2.putdata(img)
im2.save('myimg.png')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did in fact get it to work by not converting the list into an array...